# Create fake data for a panel study with R

Tags: r, panel

To measure life satisfaction before, during and after third wave of covid, I want to create fake data for a panel study. I would choose as explanatory variable the number of infections and as explained variable life statifaction scaled 1-10. In addition to that, I would generate control variables like age, employment, education, living with a partner, income, race, children and lockdown (as a dummy yes/no or as different levels).

I found a package called "simdata" with that I can define data. But I have difficulties to really understand it - even how to insert there years.

Is there any other package that is more suitable to this project or have you any recommondations where I can find more informations about the package "simdata".

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something super simple you could do. Use R's build in random number generating functions then bind the vectors. You will have

Have a look at `?rnorm`

```r
life_satisf <- round(runif(n = 50, min = 1, max = 10), digits = 0)
income <-  exp(rnorm(n = 50,mean = 11, sd = 2))
df <- cbind(life_satisf, income)
df
```